# Missing MSVCP104.dll stops program from installing

Tags: windows-10

I wanted to try this CAD program.

I created an Oracle VirtualBox  Win10 Home  VM to test its features.

I get:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP104.dll was not found. ...
```

[image]

What I have tried based on searching the web..

1. redownload the program
2. Check for MS updates and install them (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)
3. download Microsoft Visual C++ (vc_redist.x64.exe) and install
4. System File Checker tool (which it said made a repair)

What else can I do?

Comment: You want [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587) instead of what you downloaded.  Be sure you download and install both files.   What I have linked to you in this comment, is contained within my answer, to a duplicate. Multiple questions about missing VC++ files is not that helpful in my opinion. SFC only applies to system files, VC++ files, are not considered system files.  The error message is accurate, you have to install the correct version of the VC++ Redistributable, in order for the application to work.

Comment: You were suppose to download the [32-bit VC++ download](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe).  In your screenshot you downloaded the 64-bit download, the application in question (SolveSpace), is a 32-bit application.

Comment: @Ramhound  Thank you for answering my question.  It Worked!!!  I **  appreciate  ** you not passing me off to some random question somewhere on the site asked by someone with a different issue.

Comment: **The duplicate I choose wasn't random**